# Android: BluetoothAdapter getBluetoothLeAdvertiser() is null

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm attempting to have device to device communication via Bluetooth but I'm running into an issue. I'm getting the `BluetoothManager` and `BluetoothAdapter` using the below code:

```
manager = (BluetoothManager)context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
adapter = manager.getAdapter();
```

After getting the adapter, I'm then trying to get the `BluetoothLeAdvertiser` for device two to be able to find and connect to device one. However, I'm running into a weird case.

`adapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` is returning `false` and `adapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()` is returning `null` which is expected except for the following:

`adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner()` does not return null and when I execute `pm list features` via ADB `feature:android.hardware.bluetooth` and `feature:android.hardware.bluetooth_le` are both listed so I would assume that `getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()` wouldn't return `null`. Am I wrong in assuming that?

I've been researching this quite a bit today and can't find a whole lot about this unique case.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that your Android device does not support bluetooth advertising.  The vast majority of newer devices do support this, but it is not universal.  Many older Android devices do not support advertising.

See [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html) for a list of devices that are known not to support advertising.